# How to have NFT that shows on etherscan

Tags: etherscan

I'm quite new to NFT and I was wondering why NFT transactions on the main net and taken from opensea are visible in the etherscan "view NFT" button while on goerli network I've not this column... am I minting them wrongly?

Here's my NFT

https://goerli.etherscan.io/token/0x83a0499b6802f95a80c563cb56707a56c49dd0be

and this is a randomly picked one from open sea, then went to etherscan

https://etherscan.io/token/0xfb10b1717c92e9cc2d634080c3c337808408d9e1?a=0xfd64b63d4a54e6b1a0aa88e6623046c54f960d00

Another question is why they have this attribute I don't have on my contract

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think that it has to do with the fact that Etherscan do not have this feature implemented on their testnet explorers. As long as the tx is successful and the contract is ERC721 you should be fine.

EDIT: The collection is visible on Opensea's testnet marketplace, so you are good.

https://testnets.opensea.io/collection/ettnfttoken